# Decode JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

```
{"2":[[[["16","23:00"]],["18","22:00"]]],"1":[["20","20:00"]]}
```

I need print values dynamically some like this:

```
<p> 2 </p>
      <ul>
        <li>16 ---- 23:00 </li>
        <li>18 ---- 22:00 </li>
     </ul>
<p> 1 </p>
      <ul>
        <li>20 --- 20:00</li>
     </ul>
```

Is array  data returned by function json_decode(); 
how can I print it like example above... thanks.
I know i need to use cycle but, can anyone me help construct it?

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 16
                                    [1] => 23:00
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 18
                            [1] => 22:00
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20
                    [1] => 20:00
                )

        )

)
```

problem, show array when i need to see value, return some like this :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 14
                                    [1] => 23:00
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 19
                            [1] => 21:00
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 15
                                    [1] => 23:00
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 17
                            [1] => 20:00
                        )

                )

        )

)

1

    Array----
    19----21:00

2

    Array----
    17----20:00
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: are you sure your json is correct? It produces nested arrays while you want them flattened

Comment: You again have not tried anything.  Try something first, and then, only then, will we help you.

Comment: just because you are new here, you should accept an answer when you think it's valid. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use json_decode function

**Example:**

```
<?php
$a = json_decode('{"2":[[["16","23:00"],["18","22:00"]]],"1":[[["20","20:00"]]]}',true);
foreach($a as $i=>$b){
    echo "<p>";
    echo $i;
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($b as $c){
        foreach($c as $d){
            echo "<li>";
            echo $d[0] . "----" . $d[1];
            echo "</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I know, but can u show me an example how can i do it using $arrJson = json_decode('{"2":[[[["16","23:00"]],["18","22:00"]]],"1":[["20","20:00"]]}', true);

Comment: I need print values dinamically some like this:

<p> 2 </p>
      <ul>
        <li>16 ---- 23:00 </li>
        <li>18 ---- 22:00 </li>
     </ul>
<p> 1 </p>
      <ul>
        <li>20 --- 20:00</li>
     </ul>

Comment: @user2006649 You also need to read the comment under your question.

Comment: @user2006649 Not until you try something first.

Comment: Try to understand the new Example . (I have changed JSON code,your code doesn't work).

Answer (score 2):

You need to flatten the array.
Try with this:

```
<?
function array_flatten_recursive($array) {
   if (!$array) return false;
   $flat = array();
   $RII = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
   foreach ($RII as $value) $flat[] = $value;
   return $flat;
}

$jencoded = '{"2":[[[["16","23:00"]],["18","22:00"]]],"1":[["20","20:00"]]}';
$jdecoded = json_decode($jencoded);

foreach ($jdecoded as $paragraph => $paragraph_values) {
        echo "<p> $paragraph </p>\n";

        echo "   <ul>\n";
        $flattened = array_flatten_recursive($paragraph_values);
        for ($i=1; $i<count($flattened); $i+=2) {
                echo "      <li>";
                echo $flattened[$i-1];
                echo " ---- ";
                echo $flattened[$i];
                echo " </li>\n";
        }
        echo "   </ul>\n";
}
?>
```

As requested in the comments by the question's author, the code below can be used to sort the output by paragraph id. Each paragraph data is sorted by time.

```
<?

$jencoded = '{"2":[[[["16","23:00"]],["18","22:00"]]],"1":[["20","20:00"]]}';

function array_flatten_recursive($array) { 
   if (!$array) return false;
   $flat = array();
   $RII = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
   foreach ($RII as $value) $flat[] = $value;
   return $flat;
}
function array_compare_by_time( $a, $b )
{
  if ($a->value == $b->value) { return 0; } 
  return ($a->value < $b->value) ? -1 : 1;
}

function array_sort_by_time($array) {
        //print_r($array);
        $a = array();

        for ($i=1; $i<count($array); $i+=2) {
                $o = new stdClass;
                $o->key = $array[$i-1];
                $o->value = $array[$i];
                $a[] = $o;
        }
        usort($a,'array_compare_by_time');
        return (array) array_flatten_recursive((array)$a);
} 

$jdecoded = (array)json_decode($jencoded);
asort($jdecoded, SORT_NUMERIC);

foreach ($jdecoded as $paragraph => $paragraph_values) {
        echo "<p> $paragraph </p>\n";

        echo "   <ul>\n";
        $flattened = array_flatten_recursive($paragraph_values);
        $flattened = array_sort_by_time($flattened);

        for ($i=1; $i<count($flattened); $i+=2) {
                echo "      <li>";
                echo $flattened[$i-1];
                echo " ---- ";
                echo $flattened[$i];
                echo " </li>\n";
        }

        echo "   </ul>\n";
}
?>
```

The output is now:

```
<p> 1 </p>
   <ul>
      <li>20 ---- 20:00 </li>
   </ul>
<p> 2 </p>
   <ul>
      <li>18 ---- 22:00 </li>
      <li>16 ---- 23:00 </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: NICE!!!!!! this works thank you, can u explain how this works?=) please.. [to vote i need reputation 15 :( ]

Comment: Sure. The key of the first array gives you the paragraph id number that you can write between <p> tags. The array_flatten_recursive() custom function will flatten the array given as parameter, that in this case is the json decoded array starting from the second level, so you can write between <ul> tags. Then, you start to walk through the flattened array step by step. Here, the array values with odd keys are the info on the left, and the values with even keys are the info on the right. Those stuff is written between <li> tags.

Comment: Can i sort result by paragraph Asc?

Comment: Yes. Substitute the json_decode line with those two lines: $jdecoded = (array)json_decode($jencoded);
asort($jdecoded, SORT_NUMERIC);

Comment: YES. With that casting, a object becomes an array

Comment: can i order "$flattened" by time "22:00" and how, tnx. ?